# Named Entity Recognition in political domain

Tags: text, nlp, classification, named-entity-recognition

For my research project in text classification, I need to identify named entities in the political domain (using NER to improve the text classification).

Where can I find the named entities in the political domain, so that I can train the classifier with?

If you know of any other dataset than the political domain let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: @eowl but you need to have at least 5 reputation to ask questions there. right?

Answer (score 1):

Following links might help you:

- [Semantic analysis of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640687/semantic-analysis-of-text/8645574#8645574)
- [Associating free text statements with pre-defined attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541179/associating-free-text-statements-with-pre-defined-attributes/8547407#8547407)